# SQL SUBSTRING vs RIGHT - Best Practice

Tags: sql, t-sql, string

I'm trying to find out the best practice when removing characters from the start of a string.

In some languages, you can use MID without a length parameter however, in TSQL the length is required.

Considering the following code, what is the best practise? (The hex string is variable length)

```
DECLARE @sHex VARCHAR(66)
SET @sHex = '0x7E260F3DA734AD4BD816B88F485CE501D843DF067C8EDCB8AC7DAD331852E04D'

PRINT RIGHT(@sHex,LEN(@sHex) -2)
PRINT SUBSTRING(@sHex,3,LEN(@sHex) -2)
PRINT SUBSTRING(@sHex,3,65535)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, the first is more expressive of your intent. The last is clearly messy (hard-coded length etc). I doubt you'd find much performance difference between the first & second, so I'd use the simplest - `RIGHT`.

Of course, if you are doing this lots, you could write a udf that encapsulates this - then if you change your mind you only have one place to change...

Answer (score 5):

+1 on the right function, it is much clearer what you want to do

Answer (score 4):

I would use the `right` function as it better shows your intent.  The `substring` function is best used for extracting strings from the middle of a longer string.

Answer (score 2):

I use the second SUBSTRING because it is more portable.  Not all dbms had LEFT and RIGHT.

Comment: This would be the least of your problems with migrating from one database to another... :)