# Relative Performance in SQLServer of Substring vs a Right-Left combo

Tags: sql-server, performance, substring

**This is a performance based question, not a "[I don't understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557619)" or "[best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503573)" question.**

I have a varchar field in a SQLServer database that is guaranteed to be longer than 7 chars.
I need to extract a char(4) field consisting of the 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th chars in the varchar.

For example if the varchar had the value 1234567890 I would be looking for the 2345 part.

Is there a performance benefit to using a substring over a right-left combo?

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(account,2,4) FROM payment
```

or

```
SELECT RIGHT(LEFT(account,5),4) FROM payment
```

I have noticed a *slight* advantage by using a right-left on a table with 1,760,335 records, but I am not sure if this is due to caching queries or the like.

**UPDATE**
I've done a bit more homework. It seems that in this case the Right-Left is ultimately performed as a Right-Substring. Is this a rule? or is it just the way SQLServer decided to skin this particular cat?
[image]

Comment: only way to be sure in your circumstances is to benchmark...

Answer (score 2):

+1 for an interesting question. Your assessment that SQL Server may significantly change each statement through optimization is probably accurate; same as your assessment that in such a large set SQL Server may be able to cache one query better than another.

Two other things come to mind that might be (vaguely) relevant:

- Memory consumption; I would be curious if the LEFT/RIGHT combo consumes slightly more memory. In theory, the return value of the first function would need to be stored so that it could be passed into the second function, though the same register might be used over and over.
- Bounds checking. A varchar is basically a pointer to the beginning of a char[] with 2 extra bytes for indicating length. This suggests that some sort of bounds checking would need to be performed when accessing a value by an index by looking at the value contained in those 2 bytes to make sure it wasn't out of range.

SQL Server is also very forgiving when making requests outside the limits of the string with both chars and varchars. The following code will run without any errors.

```
DECLARE @Test varchar(50);
SET @Test = 'Hello World';
SELECT substring(@Test, 2, 4);
SELECT substring(@Test, 2000, 5000);
```

So will:

```
SELECT right(left(@test, 500), 400);
```

My guess is that the **explanation** for the answer to your question lies in something related; unfortunately I don't **know** the answer to your question.

I would be curious if you got the same performance results using a longer string, or a char versus a varchar. Those tests could yield more insights into the internals of SQL Server.