# Separated string into specific temp table colums

Tags: sql

I am using a `RIGHT(LEFT())` method of stripping a string as each character needs to be put into its own holder so I can access it and use it for a report (each character needs to be in its own box for some reason).

There are 16 characters usually but for space and to save repition I've slimmed down the code.

What I am trying to do is put the separated character value into the corresponding column of the temp table - how is this best achieved?

I have no other use for this data once used I'll destroy it.

**Code**

```
CREATE table #StringSeparate
(
col1 varchar(1),
col2 varchar(1),
col3 varchar(1),
col4 varchar(1),
col5 varchar(1),
col6 varchar(1),
col7 varchar(1),
col8 varchar(1),
)

declare @string varchar(16)
set @string = 'tpg22052015-1204'

SELECT
LEFT(@string,1),
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,2),1),
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,3),1),
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,4),1),
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,5),1),
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,6),1),
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,7),1),
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,8),1)
INTO
#String Separate
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, are you trying to put each char into the columns of the temporary table created? Also, it looks like your code cut off, is there more?

Comment: Apologies, yes that is exactly what I'm trying to do, I'll update the Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it like:

```
CREATE table #StringSeparate
(
col1 varchar(1),
col2 varchar(1),
col3 varchar(1),
col4 varchar(1),
col5 varchar(1),
col6 varchar(1),
col7 varchar(1),
col8 varchar(1),
)
INSERT INTO #StringSeparate
SELECT
LEFT(@string,1),
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,2),1),
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,3),1),
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,4),1),
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,5),1),
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,6),1),
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,7),1),
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,8),1)
```

Or don't create temp table and do this:

```
SELECT
LEFT(@string,1) col1,
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,2),1) col2,
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,3),1) col3,
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,4),1) col4,
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,5),1) col5,
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,6),1) col6,
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,7),1) col7,
RIGHT(LEFT(@string,8),1) col8
INTO
#StringSeparate
```

It will automatically create that temp table, because `INTO` creates table.

Comment: That second part is exatly what I was looking for but kepy getting errors (syntax variety) when I tried it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on you RDBMS I suppose I might prefer SUBSTRING:

```
INSERT INTO #StringSeparate
SELECT
LEFT(@string,1),
SUBSTRING(@string,2,1),
SUBSTRING(@string,3,1),
... 
RIGHT(@string,1)
```

Comment: What's the benefit of substring over `RIIGHT(LEFT())` ?

Comment: To me, it is more clear and I prefer 1 precise function call to the two chained together.Performance wise it probably won't make any difference. In fact, I've read here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892208/substring-vs-left-in-sql-server) that LEFT is translated to a SUBSTRING in sql server.

Answer (score 1):

I made a big insert of your statement.

```
INSERT INTO #StringSeparate
VALUES
((LEFT(@string,1)),
(RIGHT(LEFT(@string,2),1)),
(RIGHT(LEFT(@string,3),1)),
(RIGHT(LEFT(@string,4),1)),
(RIGHT(LEFT(@string,5),1)),
(RIGHT(LEFT(@string,6),1)),
(RIGHT(LEFT(@string,7),1)),
(RIGHT(LEFT(@string,8),1)))
```