# Is there a faster alternative to Substring function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2012, substr

I have an SSRS report that passes a string of counties to a stored procedure.  Because of the way I had to build the report I needed to append a GUID of 36 characters to the counties.  I then strip the GUID in the stored procedure using a substring function:

```
and county IN(Select substring(item, 1, LEN(item)-36) from fnsplit(@County, ',')
```

The report runs in about 8 seconds, which is a vast improvement over the REPLACE function.  But I'd still like to get this to run faster.  Does anyone know of a better way to do this?  I'm not allowed to included indexes on tables, so that won't be an option.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828374/relative-performance-in-sqlserver-of-substring-vs-a-right-left-combo .

Comment: Sounds quite strange if the substring really is the problem. Are you sure it's not fnsplit that causes your issues? You should really include the whole statement, query plan, and since this is a function, preferably also look at performance statistics from plan cache.

Comment: The fnsplit is run on three different variables, but runs very fast.  It was only when I added the substring() that it slowed down. When I look at the execution plan for the function it only shows costs of 50% at two Table Inserts.  Is there a good way to look at statistics from a variable?  I've only been able to insert one record in place of the variable when I run the execution plan.

Comment: You say that fnsplit runs fast. It looks like a string splitter. Is there a while loop or cursor in there? As it is a table valued function is there more than 1 single statement? If so, it is a multi-statement table valued function which is usually even slower than a scalar function.

Comment: Percentages in the plan are just estimates, and in quite many cases where performance is bad, totally wrong. Check `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` it might help you figure out what's going on

Comment: Yes, there is a while loop in the splitter.  I tried the recommendation of loading the values into a table variable first.  Surprisingly this took about 10 times longer.

Comment: My bad about the table variable taking 10x times longer.  I linked to the wrong SP.  I just ran it and took about 3 seconds, so it seems to work great.  Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

If you load it into a table variable first, then inner join, you'd probably maximize your speed.

```
DECLARE @COUNTYLIST TABLE ([County] varchar(36) PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO @COUNTYLIST ([County])
    Select substring(item, 1, LEN(item)-36) from fnsplit(@County, ',')

SELECT ...
FROM ... INNER JOIN @COUNTYLIST as [CountyList] 
    ON ...[County] = [CountyList].[County]
```

Comment: Since that will be most likely estimated to contain 1 row, you might also want to try what happens with `option (recompile)` -- assuming your report isn't executed so often that recompile becomes an issue.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work because I need to pass the @county parameter back to SSRS and table variables don't work this way.  Maybe creating another temp table instead of a table variable would work.  I'll have to try this in the morning.